# PHP code does not run and does not provide any errors

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the main page (index.php) and a database page (DB.php). Index.php makes a call at the DB page. The code appears to show no errors, but the results do not appear, which in this case is an echo statement.

```html
<?php 
require_once 'core/init.php';

DB::getInstance();
```

This is index.php

```html
<?php  
class DB{
     private static $_instance = null;
     private $_pdo, 
             $_query,
             $_error = false,
             $_results, 
             $_count= 0;

    public function _construct(){
      try{$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host'). ';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
         echo "sad";
     }catch(PDOException $e){
      die($e->getMessage());
     }
        }
public static function getInstance(){
      if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
return self::$_instance;
}

}
```

This is DB.php

Comment: what is your expected results ?

Comment: a print of 'sad'. its set up as an echo in the _construct function

Comment: assign `DB::getInstance();` to a variable and `var_dump()` it

Comment: just did that. am only getting the first half of up untill $count = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error here:

```
public function _construct() {
```

should be two underscores:

```
public function __construct() {
```

It just seems the constructor is not called which would explain the entire behavior.